# How to update data in same row as when i click on submit it adds new row in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to update same row which i fetch for edit from table, as when i click on edit button it gives me data in form again with appropriate field but when i edit data and click submit than it adds new row which should not happen as i m just editing data not adding new row so please someone help me, i will appreciate that

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var count =1;
    $("#submit_Button").on('click',function()
    {
    if($("#hidden_Id").val() == 0)
    {
        console.log($("#hidden_Id").val());

        var firstName_Field = $("#firstName").val();
        console.log(firstName_Field);
        var lastName_Field = $("#lastName").val();
        console.log(lastName_Field);
        var address = $("#address").val();
        console.log(address);

        if($("#firstName").val() == null ||$("#firstName").val() == "" && $("#lastName").val() == null ||$("#lastName").val() == "" && $("#address").val() == null ||$("#address").val() == "" )
        {
            alert("Please fill the form");
        }
        else
        {

        $("#tbl").append('<tr id="trCount"><td id="count" class="count_Class">'+ count +'</td><td id="fName" class="fname_Class">'+firstName_Field+'</td><td id="lName" class="lName_Class">'+lastName_Field+'</td><td id="addr" class="addr_Class">'+address+'</td><td id="editButton" class="editButton_Class"><input type="button" value="Edit" id="edit_Button" class="edit_Button_Class"></td>');
        count++;

        $("#firstName").val('');
        $("#lastName").val('');
        $("#address").val('');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var firstName_Field = $("#firstName").val();        
        var lastName_Field = $("#lastName").val();      
        var address = $("#address").val();

        var row_Number = $("#tbl > tbody  >tr >td:first").text();
        alert(row_Number);

        //How do i update this in table with same row
        $("#tbl").append('<tr id="trCount"><td id="count" class="count_Class">'+ count +'</td><td id="fName" class="fname_Class">'+firstName_Field+'</td><td id="lName" class="lName_Class">'+lastName_Field+'</td><td id="addr" class="addr_Class">'+address+'</td><td id="editButton" class="editButton_Class"><input type="button" value="Edit" id="edit_Button" class="edit_Button_Class"></td>');
        count++;

        $("#firstName").val('');
        $("#lastName").val('');
        $("#address").val('');
        $("#hidden_Id").val();
    }

    });


    $(document).on('click','.edit_Button_Class', function()
    {

        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var fname_Field = tr.find(".fname_Class").text();       
        var lname_Field = tr.find(".lName_Class").text();   
        var addre_Field = tr.find(".addr_Class").text();

        $("#firstName").val(fname_Field);
        $("#lastName").val(lname_Field);
        $("#address").val(addre_Field);


        var row_Count = $(this).closest('tr').index()+1;        
        $("#hidden_Id").val(row_Count);

    });

});

</script>
<style>
.myForm{
    margin-left:500px;
    width:auto;
}
#firstName{margin-left: 20px;}
#lastName{margin-left:17px;}
#address{margin-left:33px;}
#submit_Button{margin-left:87px;}
#tbl{margin-left:500px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form" action="" class="myForm">
<table>
<tr>
<td>First Name :<input type="text" id="firstName" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name : <input type="text" id="lastName"  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address :   <input type="text" id="address"   /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" class="hidden_Class" id="hidden_Id" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<td><input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit_Button" />
</table>
</form>
<table id="tbl">
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `append` and add row

Comment: could you please elaborate where to use append and add row, as i already used append please check

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').empty()`

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').append('<td id="count" class="count_Class">'+ count +'</td><td id="fName" class="fname_Class">'+firstName_Field+'</td><td id="lName" class="lName_Class">'+lastName_Field+'</td><td id="addr" class="addr_Class">'+address+'</td><td id="editButton" class="editButton_Class"><input type="button" value="Edit" id="edit_Button" class="edit_Button_Class"></td>');`